# How to play/listen buffer chunks in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create an app in react native to speak in microphone and listen at the same time.
I tried the [react-native-live-audio-stream](https://github.com/xiqi/react-native-live-audio-stream) package which streams the microphone.
Here is the sample code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { NativeBaseProvider, Button} from 'native-base';
import LiveAudioStream from 'react-native-live-audio-stream';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

export default class TestMic extends Component {

    startListenToMic(){
        LiveAudioStream.init({
            sampleRate: 32000,  
            channels: 1,       
            bitsPerSample: 16, 
            audioSource: 6,   
            bufferSize: 4096    
        });

        LiveAudioStream.on('data', data => {
            let chunk = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');  // => What I am supposed to do with this data to listen them?
            console.log(chunk) 
        })

        LiveAudioStream.start();
    }

    stopListenToMic(){
        LiveAudioStream.stop();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <NativeBaseProvider>
                <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <Button
                            onPress={ () => this.startListenToMic() }
                            mr={3}
                        >Start</Button>
                        <Button
                            onPress={ () => this.stopListenToMic() }
                            ml={3}
                        >Stop</Button>
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </NativeBaseProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

and this is the data log in console:
[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWw09.jpg)

What is the best way to convert data to audio and listen ?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No! I switched to flutter.

Comment: I finally played the data using `AudioTrack` from Android API.

Comment: Use this - react-native-audio-record - https://github.com/goodatlas/react-native-audio-record - to save and play.